# Why the pyramid can be color using GL_SMOOTH while the other one cube was just colored like a GL_FLAT one?

Tags: opengl, opengl-compat

This code is to draw one pyramid and one cube. I am trying to colour them using `GL_SMOOTH` type by `glShadeModel`. But the result is that only the pyramid can be smooth while another one cube was only colored like a `GL_FLAT` one.

It seems that there are some problems with the normal vectors but I was poor at this aspect.

Here are my codes below:

```
void initGL() {

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                   // Set background depth to farthest
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enable depth testing for z-culling
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);    // Set the type of depth-test
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
}
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    glTranslatef(1.5f, 0.0f, -7.0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
       glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
       glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);
       glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);

      // Bottom face (y = -1.0f)
       glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);     // Orange
       glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

      // Front face  (z = 1.0f)
       glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
       glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
       glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

      // Back face (z = -1.0f)
       glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Yellow
       glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);

      // Left face (x = -1.0f)
       glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
       glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

      // Right face (x = 1.0f)
       glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Magenta
       glVertex3f(1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
       glVertex3f(1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
       glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
       glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glEnd();  // End of drawing color-cube

   // Render a pyramid consists of 4 triangles
    glLoadIdentity();                  // Reset the model-view matrix
    glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f);  // Move left and into the screen

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);           // Begin drawing the pyramid with 4 triangles
      // Front
       glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
       glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
       glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
       glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
       glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); 

      // Right
       glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
       glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
       glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
       glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
       glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
       glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

      // Back
       glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
       glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
       glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
       glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
       glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
       glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

      // Left
       glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);       // Red
       glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
       glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);       // Blue
       glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);
       glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);       // Green
       glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();   // Done drawing the pyramid

    glutSwapBuffers();  // Swap the front and back frame buffers (double buffering)
}
```

Can someone tell me how could this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you draw the pyramid, then you've one color associated to each vertex coordinate of the triangle primitives. e.g:

> ```cpp
> glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
> glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
> glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
> glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
> glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
> glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
> ```

This causes that the colors of the vertices (corner) are interpolated on the triangle.

When you draw the cube then you've set one color fro each quad. Each corner of the quad is associated to the same color:

> ```cpp
> glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
> glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
> glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
> glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);
> glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);
> ```

This causes that the entire quad primitiv is uniform colored. If you want a color gradient, then you've to associate different colors to the vertices (corners).

Comment: Thanks. I thought I missed such a big mistake in my mind

Comment: But is the interpolation of colours in each vertice related to the normals?